# Mocha, Sinon and Chai testing two http calls inside a callback

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I am doing some really simple testing with Chai Mocha and Sinon. I am wondering how you would go about testing a http method that gets called inside of a callback. Please point me in the right direction if you can, struggling to find anything on it, I know you can do it, just not sure how. My code is below:

***index.js***

```
const http = require('http')

class Index {
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }

  get(uri) {
    http.get(uri, () => {
      http.get('/', function() {
        return
      })
    })
  }
}

module.exports = Index
```

index.spec.js

```
const Index = require('../index')
const http = require('http')
const { stub, fake, assert } = require('sinon')
const { expect } = require('chai')

let httpSpy;

beforeEach(function () {
  a = new Index()
  httpSpy = stub(http, 'get')
})

describe('When the get method is invoked', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    a.get('http://www.google.co.uk')
  })

  it('should make a call to the http service with passed in uri', function () {
    assert.calledOnce(httpSpy) // This really should be called twice (Part I am struggling with)
    assert.calledWith(httpSpy, 'http://www.google.co.uk')
    // I want to test instead that the httpSpy was called twice as, inside the get method, when the first http get resolves, another one gets fired off also
  })
})
```

Comment: I only see one get call being made.

Comment: The get method calld http.get and then inside the callback of the first http get method another http get method is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues.

Firstly, we cannot tell when the `Index.get()` method execution is ended (it does not accept a callback, neither return a promise, not marked as async etc).

```
get(uri) { ... }
```

Usage of such method is critically inconvenient. For example: if we'd want to first do `Index.get()` and then do some action right after we won't be able to.

To fix the this we can just add a callback as a last parameter of `Index.get`.

The second issue is how the `http.get` method is stubbed:

```
httpSpy = stub(http, 'get')
```

This line basically means: replace `http.get` with an empty function. That dummy function won't throw if you pass a callback inside **but** it won't call it.

That is why `http.get` is called only once. It simply ignores the passed callback where `http.get` should be called the second time.

To fix this we can use `stub.yields()` method to make sinon aware that the last parameter passed to a stub is a callback (and sinon needs to call it). You can find the method in [the docs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v5.0.10/stubs/).

Here is a working example, please see my comments:

```js
class Index {
    // Added a callback here
    get(uri, callback) {
        http.get(uri, () => {
            http.get('/', () => {
                // Pass any data you want to return here
                callback(null, {});
            })
        })
    }
}

let httpSpy;

beforeEach(() => {
    a = new Index()
    // Now sinon will expect a callback as a last parameter and will call it
    httpSpy = stub(http, 'get').yields();
})

describe('When the get method is invoked', () => {
    const uri = 'http://www.google.co.uk';

    // Now we are waiting for the execution to end before any assertions
    beforeEach(done => {
        a.get(uri, done);
    });

    it('should make a call to the http service with passed in uri', () => {
        assert.calledTwice(httpSpy);
        assert.match(httpSpy.getCall(0).args[0], uri);
        assert.match(httpSpy.getCall(1).args[0], '/');
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you Antonio! I did figure this out later on that night but your explanation has helped me understand why I had yield the request